# Number of sequences of $0$s, $1$s, and $2$s with length $n$ such that there is a $0$ somewhere between every pair of $2$s

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Let $a(n)$ be the number of sequences with length $n$ which consists the digits $0,1,2$ such that between every two occurrences of $2$ there is an occurrence of $0$ (not necessarily next to the $2$'s). An example for good sequence is $0102102$. An example for bad sequence is $01212$.

> A. Find a recursion formula for $a(n)$
>
> B. Find an explicit expression for $a(n)$.

**My try:**
let $x(n)$ be the number of sequences with length $n$ that if we add $2$ at the end of sequence it is still a good sequence with length $n+1$.

Now, if the last digit in the sequence was $0$, then we have to look on the number of good sequences with length $n-1$, hence $\displaystyle a(n-1)$.

If the last digit was $1$, then we now need to look on $x(n-1)$ and work with the same manipulation. This way we get the recursion $x(n)=a(n-1)+x(n-1)$. By induction I can get a recursion formula for $x(n)$, but I don't know how to find a formula for $a(n)$ or find an explicit expression for $a(n)$.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x(n) = x(n-1) + x(n-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x(n-1 -i) + x(0), n\ge 2  $
$x(0)=1$ $, x(1)=3$.

Any valid string either start with $0$ (number of such strings are $x(n-1)$) or $1$ (number of such strings are $x(n-1))$ or $2$.If it starts with $2$ then it must have only $1's$ before first occurrence of $0$. Condition on the position of first $0$ after the $2$. It can be next to it, or one $1$ followed by $0$ an so on and the case that occurrence of $2$ is followed by only $1's$ (number of such strings are $x(0))$.

**Edit**

**More Simpler Recurrence**

Using the recurrence above subtract $x(n-1)$ from $x(n)$ to get this simpler recurrence,
$$x(n)= 3x(n-1)-x(n-2), n \ge 2 $$

You can use this formula to compute the closed formula easily.

Comment: I am confused, is your $x(n)$ the OP's $a(n)$?

Comment: yes, it is. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @arindammitra, thank you for an excellent answer! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following:
\begin{align*}
r(n) &:= \text{number of sequences of 0s and 1s} = 2^n \\
s(n) &:= \text{number of sequences of 0s and 1s with at least one $0$} = 2^n - 1 \\
\end{align*}
The corresponding (ordinary) generating functions are
\begin{align*}
R(x) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} 2^n x^n = \frac{1}{1 - 2x} \\
S(x) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (2^n - 1) x^n = \frac{1}{1 - 2x} - \frac{1}{1 - x}
= \frac{x}{(1-2x)(1-x)}.
\end{align*}
The generating function $A(x)$ of $a(n)$ satisfies, by casework on the number $k$ of $2$s in the sequence:
\begin{align*}
A(x)
&= \underbrace{R(x)}_{k=0} + \underbrace{R(x) x R(x)}_{k=1} + \sum_{k \ge 2} R(x) (x S(x))^{k-1} x R(x) \\
&= R(x) + \sum_{k \ge 1} R(x)^2 S(x)^{k-1} x^{k}  \\
&= R(x) + \frac{x R(x)^2}{1 - x S(x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - 2x} + \frac{x / (1 - 2x)^2}{1 - \frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1-2x)}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - 2x} + \frac{x(1-x)}{(1-2x) \left[ (1-2x)(1-x) - x^2 \right]} \\
&= \frac{1 - 3x + x^2}{(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x + x^2)} + \frac{x - x^2}{(1-2x)(1 - 3x + x^2)} \\
&= \frac{1 - 2x}{(1 - 2x)(1 - 3x + x^2)} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{1}{1 - 3x + x^2}}.
\end{align*}

---

Now that we have the generating function, we realize that $a(n)$ satisfies a **much simpler recurrence:**
$$
a(n) = 3 a(n-1) - a(n-2)
$$
which follows directly from $A(x) (1 - 3x + x^2) = 1$.
This recurrence can be explained combinatorially as well, and if we had bothered
to be a bit more clever we might have found the recurrence in the first place and saved some algebra.

Conclude either from the recurrence or from searching the first few values [in oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+8%2C+21%2C+55&language=english&go=Search)
that in fact
$$
a(n) = f(2n+2)
$$
where $f(k)$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a(n)$ be the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ that have a $2$ after the last $0$.  Let $b(n)$ be the number of acceptable strings of length $n$ that do not have a $2$ after the last zero.  You have a pair of recurrences $a(n)=a(n-1)+b(n-1)$ because to get one you can append a $1$ to an $a$ or a $2$ to a $b$. $b(n)=2b(n-1)+a(n-1)$ because you can append either a $0$ or $1$ to a $b$ or append a $0$ to an $a$.  Starting conditions are $a(1)=1, b(1)=2$  It turns out the $a$'s and $b$'s are alternate Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Galc127, there are 3 disjoint cases that you must want to take into account.$$B_n=\{x\in \{0,1,2\}^n: x = r21^k ,r\in A_{n-k-1}\},$$is the set of good words that ends up with a $2$.
$$C_n=\{x\in \{0,1,2\}^n: x = r2p0q ,r\in A_{n-k-2}\wedge pq\in \{0,1\}^k\},$$
Is the set of good words that ends up with $2$ and $0$.
$$D_n=\{0,1\}^n,$$is the set that does not have any $2$'s.
Therefore, $A_n=B_n\cup C_n\cup D_n$, and call $a_n=|A_n|,b_n=|B_n|,c_n=|C_n|,d_n=|D_n|$. The sets are disjoint so $a_n=b_n+c_n+d_n$ and $d_n=2^n$.
Now,  $$b_n=d_{n-1}+c_{n-1}+b_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+c_{n-1}+b_{n-1},$$$$c_n=2*c_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$$
**Do you see why?**(try by appending proper characters at the end of strings in each set)

The thing with your try is that you are not using $B_n$ anywhere, your $x_n$ is like $d_n+c_n$.

Hope it helps.
**Edit:**
As a comment, the generating function would be $$\frac{1}{1-2x}+\frac{x^2}{1-5x+7x^2-2x^3}+\frac{x}{1-3x+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $w$ be an arbitrary good word of length $n$.  To extend $w$ to a good word of length $n+1$,

we have 3 choices for the last digit.  The resulting word will always be good if the last digit is 0 or 1,

so we need to subtract the number of bad words that result when we append a 2:

Let T be the set of bad words of length $n+1$ which become good when the last digit (2) is deleted, and

let S be the set of good words of length $n-1$;

we will show below that T and S have the same number of elements, so then

$\hspace{.5 in}\color {red}{a(n+1)=3a(n)-a(n-1)}$.

---

$\textbf{1)} $Define $f:T\rightarrow S$ by deleting the last two digits.

$\textbf{2)} $Define $g:S\rightarrow T$ as follows:

$\;\;\;\textbf{a)}$ If $v$ ends in 0, let $g(v)=v22$.

$\;\;\;\textbf{b)}$ If $v$ ends in 2, let $g(v)=v12$.

$\;\;\;\textbf{a)}$ If $v$ ends in 1, let $g(v)=\begin{cases}v22, &\mbox{if v has a 0 after the last 2 (if any)}\\ v12, &\mbox{if v does not have a 0 after the last 2} \end{cases}$

Since $f$ and $g$ are clearly inverses, S and T have the same number of elements.